# Integral and radius of convergence

Tags: calculus

I have never met such a problem with integral and expansion,how should I approach it?

Using Maclaurin series to find the radius of convergence of
$$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \ln{(t+\sqrt{t^2+1})} \, dt.
$$

Comment: Isn't that an inverse hyperbolic function in the integrand?

Comment: @Chappers it sounds beyond my knowledge as a first year in university

Comment: It's the inverse function, $x=\arg\sinh{t}$ of $t=\sinh{x}$, where $\sinh{x} = \frac{1}{2}(e^x-e^{-x})$, as you can see by rearranging and solving for $e^x$, then taking logs. Therefore the answer should be, I would guess, $1$, since that is the radius of convergence of the $\arg\sinh$. Goodness knows how you're supposed to get from the integral to a Maclaurin series, though.

Comment: Hint: the radius of convegence of $f$ is the same as that of $f'$.

Comment: **Hint:** Let $t=\sinh u$.

Answer (score 2):

You may notice that:
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\log(t+\sqrt{t^2+1}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\tag{1}$$
and since:
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}t^{2n}\tag{2} $$
with radius of convergence equal to one$^{(*)}$, we have:
$$ \log(t+\sqrt{t^2+1}) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)\,4^n}\binom{2n}{n}t^{2n+1}\tag{3}$$
and:
$$ \int_{0}^{x}\log(t+\sqrt{t^2+1})\,dt = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(2n+2)\,4^n}\binom{2n}{n}x^{2n+2}\tag{4}$$
still with the same radius of convergence, $\color{red}{1}$. In general, an analytic function in a neighbourhood of the origin and its primitive always have the same radius of convergence, since the transformation:
$$\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n z^n \quad\longrightarrow\quad \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{a_n}{n+1} z^{n+1}$$
leaves it unchanged, as a consequence of $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$.

<sup>$(*)$ $(2)$ may be regarded as a special case of the binomial theorem for non-integer exponents. 

We just have to find the Taylor series of $(1-z)^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha=-\frac{1}{2}$ then replace $z$ with $-t^2$.</sup>